# How to validate ip address in C#

Tags: c#, regex, validation, ip, ip-address

I'm doing an application that uses IP address. I have to validate them to start from at least 1.0.0.1 but with the codes below it accepts 0.0.0.0:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

I also tried changing it to:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

This code does not accept 0.0.0.0 but does not accept 100.0.0.0 to 109.0.0.0 either.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please learn how to format your questions properly.

Comment: -1 for not explaining that you are using regex (if that's what it is). What is "bt"? Why is the formatting so poor? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Using Regex for this kind of validation seems needlessly brain-taxing. Why not split by `.` and validate each portion of the IP address in a more conventional way?

Comment: everyone is really harsh today...

Comment: @spender, @ba_friend: Why not help edit the post to improve the formatting rather than just complaining? You both have the rep to help!

Comment: Frankly, the initial edit of the question was sufficiently poor that in order to make it proper, I would need to make assumptions about OPs intent that might not be correct.

Comment: @Luke, @xan I edited this post before @Mat and before I commented on this. Changed the title, tags, and formatting even fixed the `bt` typo. ;)

Comment: But did it really need to be -1? surely that is what notes are for? You nurture and get the information, someone with a low 100 score isnt going to know how the site works off the bat. Help them to grow and become part of the community. I'll get off my soapbox in a sec. I think this is a constant debate. I'll see if this on meta. I understand that as a community site we are responsible for content, but for a youngling to come in and be marked down by -2 before they even get going. how are we suppose to grow the community with such harsh ideals. Nurture a Noob today. you'll feel a lot better.

Comment: @Luke, I understand your concern. Just to be clear I edited the post **but** I did not downvote, even if it looked like because 2 comments and 2 downvotes at that moment.

Comment: \/ Save your self even more pain and prepare for IPV6 with IPaddress.tryparse !

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
IPAddress addr = IPAddress.TryParse(str);
```

Then, if that worked get the numbers using

```
addr.GetAddressBytes();
```

and then check the byte values for the correct conditions using normal if-cases.

Comment: bye the way it also validates 1 as true and set the ipaddress to 0.0.0.1

Comment: Yes "1" is a valid IP address, meaning 0.0.0.1

Comment: Yap for network expert it might be understandable, but validation on input text box on an application for non-professional user is not desired.

Comment: The question was how to validate that the individual bytes in the address have appropriate values. In this specific case the requirement was that it was at least 1.0.0.1, which would only be possible from a string containing four octets. If you want to accept *any* IP address but validate that the user has input all four octets then parsing in this way will not be sufficient.

Comment: I already voted up the answer, i just added my first note for developer who are looking for ip address string validation. like me. :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself the pain! Convert to a string, split on the dot character and check whether each of the 4 segments is in the range 0 or 1 to 255.

Otherwise if you use RegexBuddy (which is a fantastic app for RegEx) it has a bunch of IP address examples in the Library inc for 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
ValidIpAddressRegex = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
```